How to limit number of virtual threads to avoid large number of DB connections?
I am currently using Executors.newFixedThreadPool to run a large number of tasks in parallel.
try(ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)) {
        List<Future<Integer>> resultFutures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        for (Future<Integer> rf: resultFutures ) {
                    ....
         }
         executorService.shutdown();
 }

Each task opens a DB connection.
I want to use virtual threads for same(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()).
But it may lead to large number of DB connections.
I searched, but couldn't find a way to limit number of virtual threads.
What is a better way of dealing with this situation?

Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, Thread.ofVirtual().factory())

You could also use a DB connection pool with a limited number of connections. This would also save the time to set up and close a connection for each task/thread.

give forkJoinPool a try,link-https://java-8-tips.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forkjoin.html#forkjoinpool

Virtual threads should not be pooled.
So we need to directly throttle our use of expensive resources.
By the way, be aware that enterprise-oriented database servers such as Postgres  offer various ways of limiting connections. These have the advantage of being managed by the DBA/SysAdmin rather than the Java programmer. But here I focus on your Question asking about limiting Java virtual threads.
java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
Semaphore is a common way to limit the number of objects simultaneously accessing a resource.
Instantiate a Semaphore, specifying a limited number of permits. You likely want to mark the object reference static and final.
static final databaseConnectionLimitSemaphore = new Semaphore ( 42 ) ;

Your code grabs one of the permits by calling acquire. If no permit is available, the acquire call blocks until one becomes available. Blocked virtual threads are very efficient, being set aside (“parked”) to allow other virtual threads to execute.
When done using that resource, return the permit by calling release. Be sure to use try-finally syntax to ensure no permit is lost.
try
{
    databaseConnectionLimitSemaphore.acquire() ;  // Blocks until a permit becomes available. 
    … get your database connection …
    … do your database work …
}
finally
{
    databaseConnectionLimitSemaphore.release() ;  // Return permit to the semaphore. 
}


Don't make your own connection pool implementation, better to use existing implementations like the one in tomcat.

@AminM No pool involved. I don’t recommend database connection pooling except in the most demanding situations.

I'd argue that if it isn't a demanding situation, I wouldn't worry about it an use an existing connection pooling implementation rather than rolling my own concurrent code, and worrying about runaway connections, and not having the monitoring tools at my disposal that standard implementations have.

@AminM Using recycled database connections comes with its own risks and challenges. And the history of database connection pooling implementations is not pretty, littered with flaws and problems. In most cases, I’ll take fresh connections with this simple Semaphore code over any DB connection pooling. But to each his own. The Question asked for a way to limit virtual threads, and I gave my Answer. Perhaps you should post your own Answer.

@BasilBourque I would be interested to read about specific "flaws and and problems" with DB connection pooling. Do you have any references?

downvoted: task implementation violates SOLID principals.

I'd also say, use a connection pool. Most will already block when all connections are in use and thus will act like a semaphore anyway. And saying not to use a connection pool sounds a lot like FUD or cargo-cult.

@BasilBourque you should be able to configure whether they recycle or not

chore: Should the example have databaseConnectionLimitSemaphore.release, instead of current databaseConnectionLimitSemaphore.return?

@Touko Yes, my bad. Fixed. Thank you.

@AndreyB.Panfilov, could you elaborate on the violation of SOLID principles? As the answer currently stands, if offers, IMHO, rather innocent, although potentially excessive, layer of restriction over traditional DB connection pool and might be useful in some specific cases.

it violates both SRP and LSP principles. As regards to using jdbc pools I would rather agree with @BasilBourque for this particular case - jdbc pools are not designed for such patters, check "Pool-locking" in https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing
